# Python-2.7.13 syntaxerror

Tags: python

When I run below command (line 13) with quotations, I get syntax error:

```
list1 = ["SuperMan", "BatMan", "The Mask", "SpiderMan"];

#print entire list
print "The list is: \n", list1

#reverse the list
list1.reverse()

#print entire list
print "\nThe reversed list is: \n", list1

#print the index of an object within the list
print "\nThe object "The Mask" is at index: ", list1.index("The Mask")

#remove object from the list
list1.remove("SpiderMan")

#print entire list
print "\nAfter Removing SpiderMan: \n", list1
```

run the file

```
PS C:\Users\xxx> python listfun.py
  File "listfun.py", line 13
    print "\nThe object "The Mask" is at index: ", list1.index("The Mask")
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Line 13, does not like quotations before The and after Mask
"The Mask"
If I remove the quotations, it will produce the answer without quotations but that is not correct.

```
list1 = ["SuperMan", "BatMan", "The Mask", "SpiderMan"];

#print entire list
print "The list is: \n", list1

#reverse the list
list1.reverse()

#print entire list
print "\nThe reversed list is: \n", list1

#print the index of an object within the list
print "\nThe object The Mask is at index: ", list1.index("The Mask")

#remove object from the list
list1.remove("SpiderMan")

#print entire list
print "\nAfter Removing SpiderMan: \n", list1
```

run the file again

```
PS C:\Users\xxx> python listfun.py
The list is:
['SuperMan', 'BatMan', 'The Mask', 'SpiderMan']

The reversed list is:

['SpiderMan', 'The Mask', 'BatMan', 'SuperMan']

The object The Mask is at index:  1

After Removing SpiderMan:
['The Mask', 'BatMan', 'SuperMan']
```

Comment: you have quotes within your quotes. use single quotes or backslash them... `print '\nThe object "The Mask" is at index: ', list1.index("The Mask")` would do.

Comment: That is, the same character `"` is used begin and end a string literal, and they do not stack like parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

This example demonstrates how useful code highlighting is. If some parts of a string have a different color, then something is wrong :-)
To fix the problem, you need to esacpe the quotes inside the String

```
print "\nThe object "The Mask" is at index: ", list1.index("The Mask")
```

should be:

```
print "\nThe object \"The Mask\" is at index: ", list1.index("The Mask")
```

Comment: Very nice. I got this samples form a programming app called "programming" They author probably did not test his work before publishing it. Thanks!

Comment: you are welcome! :-)

Answer (score 1):

In python, single and double quotes are interchangeable provided that you match them.  You also have the option of using a multi-line string literal with a triple/double quotes.

`print "\nThe object "The Mask" is at index: ", list1.index("The Mask")`

What really happened is that python tried to interpret `The` as a variable/word.

To fix, you need to escape the double quotes or use single quotes as below:

`print "\nThe object 'The Mask' is at index: ", list1.index("The Mask")`

or (with escape characters):

`print "\nThe object \"The Mask\" is at index: ", list1.index("The Mask")`

or (swapping double quotes with single quotes):

`print '\nThe object "The Mask" is at index:`, list1.index("The Mask")`

You can also use a multi-line string literal with triple quotes or single quotes as follows:

`print '''\nThe object "The Mask" is at index: ''', list1.index("The Mask")`

or (with double quotes):

`print """\nThe object "The Mask" is at index: """, list1.index("The Mask")`

Comment: `print 'The object "The Mask" is at index: ', list1.index("The Mask")` is a third option, possibly preferable to the first, since it preserves the type of quotation marks actually displayed in the output.

Comment: If you use single quotes, no need to escape them. This is also ok:

`print '\nThe object "The Mask" is at index: ', list1.index("The Mask")`

Answer (score 0):

Double quote should be escaped in line 13.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to escape if you pair the quotes with the same kind. It just concatenates strings as if there's a `+` in between the `str` objects.

```
print "\nThe object" "The Mask" "is at index: ", list1.index("The Mask")
```